How to make NetworkManager use `/etc` configs and where `/run` connections come from?
I have a Petalinux board (a Trenz Electronic with an AMD/Xilinx Zynq UltraScale+ MPSoC) which boots up with a wrong network connection config (no DHCP). It has no configs in /etc:
$ ls /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/
$ 

After configuring the connection with sudo nmcli con mod eth0 ... it works fine. (I modify the ipv4 and ipv6 config, like here on stackoverflow.) And it creates a permanent config file in /etc:
/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/eth0.nmconnection

But, after a reboot NetworkManager creates a new /run config, which somehow takes precedence over my connection in /etc:
$ nmcli -f TYPE,FILENAME,UUID,NAME,DEVICE connection
TYPE      FILENAME                                                  UUID                                  NAME  DEVICE 
ethernet  /run/NetworkManager/system-connections/eth0.nmconnection  99e39a32-c0ab-4b3f-be16-75a9bdff1277  eth0  eth0   
loopback  /run/NetworkManager/system-connections/lo.nmconnection    5d84c484-4214-47e4-8f00-01f7730200b3  lo    lo     
ethernet  /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/eth0.nmconnection  fb365147-6ad9-47a0-a5c8-fbea10080ece  eth0  --     

Here, the rogue 99e39a32 from /run got connected to the eth0 device, and my /etc connection config fb365147 stays idle.
How to correctly and permanently save a connection config in NetworkManager, or make it use /etc config as the only template for the eth0 connection? Where does it even get the configs for /run? How come it does not use /etc to create /run configs?
There are posts saying the NetworkManager creates connections per user. I.e. the suggestion was something like /etc is root and somehow other connections get used for my user. But I don't think that's the case here. nmcli does not let me modify a connection without root permissions.
There is a number of similar questions on the internet: 1 (I don't have /etc/netplan file which is mentioned in a comment there), 2, 3. But they don't help in my case.
Update:
There is some info how the /run config comes about thanks to the log journalctl -u NetworkManager after booting the computer with [loggin] level=TRACE in /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf:
NetworkManager[347]: <info>  [1734374462.9312] device (eth0): carrier: link connected
NetworkManager[347]: <trace> [1734374462.9313] ethtool[3]: ETHTOOL_GSET, eth0: success
NetworkManager[347]: <debug> [1734374462.9317] device[e5c0e28febbc1b13] (eth0): unmanaged: flags set to [platform-init,!user-settings=0x4/0x14/unmanaged/unrealized], set-managed [user-settings=0x10])
NetworkManager[347]: <debug> [1734374462.9318] device[e5c0e28febbc1b13] (eth0): unmanaged: flags set to [!platform-init,!user-settings=0x0/0x14/managed/unrealized], set-managed [platform-init=0x4])
NetworkManager[347]: <debug> [1734374462.9318] device[e5c0e28febbc1b13] (eth0): unmanaged: flags set to [!sleeping,!platform-init,!user-settings=0x0/0x15/managed/unrealized], set-managed [sleeping=0x1])
NetworkManager[347]: <trace> [1734374462.9319] dbus-object[e5c0e28febbc1b13]: export: "/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/2"

NetworkManager[347]: <info>  [1734374462.9329] manager: (eth0): new Ethernet device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/2)
NetworkManager[347]: <trace> [1734374462.9349] settings: auto-default: cannot create auto-default connection for device eth0: already has a profile
<----- this already existing "profile" must be the config in /etc
       when I added no-auto-default=* or eth0 in NetworkManager.conf
       this line said: cannot create auto-default.. because no-auto
...
NetworkManager[347]: <debug> [1734374462.9356] Connection 'eth0' differs from candidate 'eth0' in ipv4.addresses, ipv4.gateway, ipv4.method
NetworkManager[347]: <debug> [1734374462.9357] manager: (eth0): assume: generated connection 'eth0' (b807ebb2-d7a5-4b26-82c1-c321a6e7d5ba)
NetworkManager[347]: <debug> [1734374462.9357] device[e5c0e28febbc1b13] (eth0): assume-state: set guess-assume=0, connection=(null)
NetworkManager[347]: <trace> [1734374462.9370] keyfile: commit: b807ebb2-d7a5-4b26-82c1-c321a6e7d5ba (eth0) added as "/run/NetworkManager/system-connections/eth0.nmconnection" (nm-generated,volatile,external)

I guess the question now is what it means by Connection 'eth0' differs from candidate 'eth0' ... - what is that candidate? I.e. probably there is some more config for the eth0 device itself, and when the /etc config conflicts with that one, NetworkManager creates a new one?
I tried adding this file with no change in the behavior (it's probably deprecated):
$ cat /etc/network/interfaces
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

Update 2:
Just to point out, I have tried adding no-auto-default config, but it made no difference in this case:
/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf

[main]
no-auto-default=*
# or no-auto-default=eth0

And adding the connection in /etc/network/interfaces also did not help:
# Wired interfaces
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
    hwaddress ether <MAC address>

I think, as @telcoM suggested, it is a Petalinux-specific behavior. You define the settings for the eth0 device when the image is built (and apparently NetworkManager can somehow read settings from the device or what?), and you cannot modify ethernet settings in Petalinux after the image has been built. Probably, there is nothing that you can modify in uboot ZynqMP> console either.
So, what I ended up doing is: rename my connection to eth0dhcp and add a systemd unit that connects it after the boot.
sudo nmcli c mod fb365147-6ad9-47a0-a5c8-fbea10080ece con-name eth0dhcp

The connection config looks like:
$ sudo cat /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/eth0.nmconnection 
[connection]
id=eth0dhcp
uuid=fb365147-6ad9-47a0-a5c8-fbea10080ece
type=ethernet
autoconnect=false
interface-name=eth0
timestamp=1734377647
 
[ethernet]
mac-address=<mac address>
 
[ipv4]
method=auto
 
[ipv6]
addr-gen-mode=default
method=auto
 
[proxy]

And the one-shot systemd unit:
[Unit]
Description=UP the eth0dhcp for eth0 after boot
 
After=network.target
Requires=network.target
 
[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
User=root
ExecStart=nmcli con up eth0dhcp
 
SuccessExitStatus=0
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=20
 
StartLimitInterval=300
StartLimitBurst=5
 
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

It's enough of a workaround in my case. Later we'll just build images with whatever settings that are needed.

Where does Network Manager store settings? Does this help?

If you run NetworkManager --print-config as root, what do you get?

@telcoM top line says # NetworkManager configuration: /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf. Then everything is commented out except [main] configure-and-quit=no. The last line also says # no-auto-default file "/var/lib/NetworkManager/no-auto-default.state"

restarting sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager does not change anything. I.e. if I delete the wrong /run eth0 connection, command down and up the /etc eth0 connection, then restart NetworkManager, it does not create a new /run connection to override the /etc. Which is good to see.

In sudo journalctl -u NetworkManager I can see how the wrong connection gets set up, but there is not much details: device (eth0): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'connection-assumed', sys-iface-state: 'external') then ...state change: unavailable -> disconnected... and device (eth0): Activation: starting connection 'eth0' (a0da2935-8c1c-4cd2-b185-685762966a2a) which is the UUID of the wrong /run connection. I wonder maybe the original "unmanaged" suggests something.

Also, in /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf everything is commented out. I guess I will set [logging] level=TRACE and see what shows up in the log then.

And, unfortunately ChatGPT does not suggest anything new. It says the persistent configs are stored in /etc and are copied to /run, then processes modify them at run time.

The TRACE log is useful. It explains why it created a new connection. manager: (eth0): new Ethernet device (/org...) then settings: auto-default: cannot create auto-default connection for device eth0: already has a profile then a couple lines and Connection 'eth0' differs from candidate 'eth0' in ipv4.gateway, ipv4.method, ipv4.addresses (yep, those 3 are modified for DHCP), and the /run config: manager: (eth0): assume: generated connection 'eth0' (a766ba58-4ebb-4d7c-9085-2f49b7fe31be). Not sure what these mean, though.

Petalinux is a distribution for embedded use, and it seems to me it's designed to be configured before you create your target image, and then not modified afterwards. The configuration should happen in the Ethernet settings section of the petalinux-config tool you would run while preparing your Petalinux project.
The ChatGPT is not recognizing the fact that Petalinux is an embedded distribution, not a typical desktop/server one.
The version of NetworkManager used in Petalinux is probably minimized as much as possible. In general, NetworkManager can have multiple configuration storage plugins to match the classic configuration styles of various distributions, plus the standard keyfile plugin that is always included.
In Petalinux, there might be only the keyfile plugin present, and whatever mechanism is responsible for converting the network settings made with petalinux-config into an active NetworkManager configuration is apparently not firing just once but at every boot, and ends up fighting with your customization attempts.

yes, I think you are right. Petalinux probably has its own specific config for eth0 device.

and I think there is no way to modify the image after it has been built. I.e. there is probably nothing you can set in uboot ZynqMP> etc. So, I just add a systemd unit that launches the DHCP connection. I will put it in the question and accept your answer.

Much like systemd, configurations in /run/ are automatically generated. If you want to turn off automatic profiles for a given network interface (to force yourself to create a profile to connect Ethernet even on a DHCP network for example), you will need to configure NetworkManager to turn off the default profiles or create your own profile.
To do this, add a config file to /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/ that sets no-auto-default to the interfaces you do not want to receive automatic profiles.
[main]
no-auto-default=eth0

The remaining files in /run/NetworkManager/ are runtime system state for NetworkManager and should not be deleted.

thanks! I think you are right and it will work in the case of a normal linux. But here I tried to add no-auto-default and it made no effect. I think it is something Petalinux-specific, as telcoM suggested. I will accept his answer.
